# Multiplication of Pandas DataFrame with Pandas Series

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas `Series` `v`, with numeric entries `v0, v1, ..., vn`, and a Pandas `DataFrame` `C`, with columns `C0, C1, ..., Cn`.  I want to generate the `DataFrame` whose columns are the *n* scaled columns `C0*v0, C1*v1*, ..., Cn*vn`.

What's the "idiomatic" expression for such a product? Does this kind of product have a standard name?

Could the best solution entail working with one or both of the underlying `numpy.ndarray`'s `v.values` and `C.values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's matrix multiplication of the matrix C by the matrix with diagonal v.

For example, here's a Series v and a DataFrame C:

```
In [65]: v
Out[65]: 
0    1
1   -2
2    5
dtype: int64

In [66]: C
Out[66]: 
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
```

Here's the product:

```
In [67]: C.dot(np.diag(v))
Out[67]: 
    0   1   2
0   0  -2  10
1   3  -8  25
2   6 -14  40
3   9 -20  55
4  12 -26  70
```

You could also compute that using element-wise multiplication and broadcasting.  The DataFrame `multiply` method and the `*` operator handle broadcasting, so you can write:

```
In [102]: C * v
Out[102]: 
    0   1   2
0   0  -2  10
1   3  -8  25
2   6 -14  40
3   9 -20  55
4  12 -26  70
```

Some testing on a DataFrame with 50 rows and 100 columns shows that it is much more efficient to work with the numpy arrays, as follows:

```
In [113]: C.values * v.values
Out[113]: 
array([[  0,  -2,  10],
       [  3,  -8,  25],
       [  6, -14,  40],
       [  9, -20,  55],
       [ 12, -26,  70]])
```